# Android.Malware.General (score:6) engine detected

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, security, facebook-ads

I'm trying to implement Facebook ads on my app, but Facebook doesn't approve my app because they say it has malware.

[image]

This malware appears only when I publish my app on Play Store, before publishing, I scan it on VirusTotal, it shows that it is safe, but when I publish my app on the Play Store, the malware comes again.

I looked up a lot about this or how to fix it but no solution has found yet.

Can anyone help me out to get rid of that malware from my app?

Comment: have you found its solution , i am facing same issue so please if fixed then let me know

Comment: I solved the issue by changing the keystore I used to sign the app. However, Google Play Store requires AAB now so you don't have to worry about this issue anymore.